# Compose React component

Tags: reactjs

I'd Like to build a menu component and MenuItem, and nest the MenuItem inside the Menu. How do I achieve this structure,to compose these component in React.

```
<Menu>
 <MenuItem/>
 <MenuItem/>
</Menu>
```

This Class uses Material Light class to build a menu

```
export class Menu extends React.Component {
    public props;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<span>
            <button id="demo-menu-lower-left" className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
              <i className="material-icons">more_vert</i>
              </button>

            <ul className="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="demo-menu-lower-left">
                // childs should go here
            </ul>
            </span>);
    }
}

    export class MenuItem extends React.Component {
        public props;
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
        render() {
            return (<li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.props.children` to wrap components

```
export class Menu extends React.Component {
    public props;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<span>
            <button id="demo-menu-lower-left" className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
              <i className="material-icons">more_vert</i>
              </button>

            <ul className="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="demo-menu-lower-left">
                {this.props.children}
            </ul>
            </span>);
    }
}
```

then where ever you want to create menu you can do

```
<Menu>
  <MenuItem />
  <MenuItem />
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.props.children`

See [doc here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren)

**Menu** :

```
 render(){
   <ul>
      {this.props.children} //All content provided inside your instanciation <Menu>here</Menu>
   </ul>
 }
```

You can pass whatever you want inside....

```
<Menu>
   <li></li> 
   <MenuItem />
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default every React component receives a special props called **children**.

In the case you are not performing any composition, it's just going to be set to undefined.

```
<Menu>
 <MenuItem/>
 <MenuItem/>
</Menu>
```

In your case, Menu's this.props.children is going to represent your two MenuItem.

```
export class Menu extends React.Component {
    public props;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<span>
            <button id="demo-menu-lower-left" className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
              <i className="material-icons">more_vert</i>
              </button>

            <ul className="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="demo-menu-lower-left">
                {this.props.children}
            </ul>
            </span>);
    }
}

export class MenuItem extends React.Component {
    public props;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (<li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>);
    }
}
```

It's possible that you don't want to simply plainly render your children, so if you need to pass props to your children, or perform other types of complex operations on them. You should check out [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) which will allow you to manipulate them.